# Is it possible to make popover equal to a variable or a function?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-popover

I wonder if I can make data-content equal to a function, i.e.

```
<a data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-content="1 Ethernet<br>2 ATM">Hardware Type</a>
```

I want to have something like `data-content="CallMyFunction"`, how can I do it?

Comment: [Read this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers-options) specifically the "content" option